# SQL: How do I get parent and child records for data maintained in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is how my table (locationgroup) looks like. Parent and child relationships are being maintained at the same table and there can many more records (ids might not be in sequence)

```
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|   id | name       |   parentid |   customerid | type          | deleted   |
|------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------|
|  131 | Zone       |          0 |           79 | zone          | False     |
|  132 | State      |        131 |           79 | state         | False     |
|  136 | Center 3   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
|  134 | Center 1   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
|  135 | Center 2   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
|  133 | City       |        132 |           79 | city          | False     |
|  137 | Center 4   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
```

What I want to achieve is to get parent(s) and child(s) of any given id.

Eg: for `id - 131` the result should be

```
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|   id | name       |   parentid |   customerid | type          | deleted   |
|------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------|
|  131 | Zone       |          0 |           79 | zone          | False     |
|  132 | State      |        131 |           79 | state         | False     |
|  133 | City       |        132 |           79 | city          | False     |
|  134 | Center 1   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
|  135 | Center 2   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
|  136 | Center 3   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
|  137 | Center 4   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
```

thus, for `id - 137` the result should be

```
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|   id | name       |   parentid |   customerid | type          | deleted   |
|------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------|
|  131 | Zone       |          0 |           79 | zone          | False     |
|  132 | State      |        131 |           79 | state         | False     |
|  133 | City       |        132 |           79 | city          | False     |
|  137 | Center 4   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I am able to get only child records with my query

```
WITH RECURSIVE locgrp AS (
        SELECT
        lg.*
        FROM locationgroup lg
        WHERE lg.customerid = 79 AND lg.id IN (133) AND lg.deleted = FALSE
        UNION
        SELECT
        lg_union_1.*
        FROM locationgroup lg_union_1
        INNER JOIN locgrp lg_union_2 ON lg_union_1.parentid = lg_union_2.id
        WHERE lg_union_1.deleted = FALSE AND lg_union_2.deleted = FALSE
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM locgrp ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Eg: for `id - 137` what I get is

```
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|   id | name       |   parentid |   customerid | type          | deleted   |
|------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------|
|  137 | Center 4   |        133 |           79 | servicecentre | False     |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I can achieve the desired result by changing line

`INNER JOIN locgrp lg_union_2 ON lg_union_1.parentid = lg_union_2.id`

in query to

`INNER JOIN locgrp lg_union_2 ON lg_union_1.id = lg_union_2.parentid`

but then they're two different queries for the same purpose.

How to modify my query to get parent and child records with the same query. There's is no restriction that I should stick to recursive query or anything.

Comment: Can't you just UNION the two queries? I don't see how you can simultaneously navigate up and down the tree...

Comment: I agree with mlinth

Comment: So you want your query to traverse the tree both ways, get both parent and child records?

Comment: @mlinth - I don't have two separate queries `INNER JOIN locgrp lg_union_2 ON lg_union_1.id = lg_union_2.parentid` this was just for an example. I want to get it done with a single query only (if possible).

Comment: @Hambone - That's right.

Comment: In that case, I also agree with @mlinth -- I would write them as two recursive queries and join `union` the results.  Unfortunately, recursive queries don't support outer joins, nor do they allow multiple unions, so a union outside of the recursion seems like your only option.

Comment: @Hambone as I said I don't have any restrictions like using recursive only and etc. Then is there any way to get it done without the help of a second query?

Comment: Are you okay with a function?

Comment: @Hambone Yes, totally.

Comment: Cool...  check out my attempt and see if that gets you closer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're good with a function, something like this should work.  I don't pretend it's the coolest looking thing, but I do believe it yields the correct results:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recurse_me(cust_id integer, loc_id integer)
  RETURNS SETOF locationgroup AS
$BODY$
declare
  rw locationgroup%rowtype;
begin

  FOR rw IN
    WITH RECURSIVE locgrp AS (
      SELECT
      lg.*
      FROM locationgroup lg
      WHERE lg.customerid = cust_id AND lg.id = loc_id AND lg.deleted = FALSE
      UNION
      SELECT
      lg_union_1.*
      FROM locationgroup lg_union_1
      INNER JOIN locgrp lg_union_2 ON lg_union_1.parentid = lg_union_2.id
      WHERE lg_union_1.deleted = FALSE AND lg_union_2.deleted = FALSE
    )
    SELECT * FROM locgrp
  LOOP
    return next rw;
  END LOOP;

  FOR rw IN
    WITH RECURSIVE locgrp AS (
      SELECT
      lg.*
      FROM locationgroup lg
      WHERE lg.customerid = cust_id AND lg.id = loc_id AND lg.deleted = FALSE
      UNION
      SELECT
      lg_union_1.*
      FROM locationgroup lg_union_1
      INNER JOIN locgrp lg_union_2 ON lg_union_1.id = lg_union_2.parentid
      WHERE lg_union_1.deleted = FALSE AND lg_union_2.deleted = FALSE
    )
    SELECT * FROM locgrp where id != loc_id
  LOOP
    return next rw;
  END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Implementation:

```
postgres=# select * from recurse_me (79, 133) order by id;
 id  |     name     | parentid | customerid |      type       | deleted
-----+--------------+----------+------------+-----------------+---------
 131 |  Zone        |        0 |         79 |  zone           | f
 132 |  State       |      131 |         79 |  state          | f
 133 |  City        |      132 |         79 |  city           | f
 134 |  Center 1    |      133 |         79 |  servicecentre  | f
 135 |  Center 2    |      133 |         79 |  servicecentre  | f
 136 |  Center 3    |      133 |         79 |  servicecentre  | f
 137 |  Center 4    |      133 |         79 |  servicecentre  | f
(7 rows)

postgres=# select * from recurse_me (79, 137) order by id;
 id  |     name     | parentid | customerid |      type       | deleted
-----+--------------+----------+------------+-----------------+---------
 131 |  Zone        |        0 |         79 |  zone           | f
 132 |  State       |      131 |         79 |  state          | f
 133 |  City        |      132 |         79 |  city           | f
 137 |  Center 4    |      133 |         79 |  servicecentre  | f
(4 rows)
```